# How to fix problem with NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

During work on my kotlin project using InteliJ IDE suddenly I get following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
>
> at com.beust.klaxon.DefaultConverter.(DefaultConverter.kt)

[image]

My old code which compile without problems now throw this exception. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the reason - but this helps: reload gradle by click on

[image]

After that error disappear. I hope someone give explanation in separate answer

Comment: There's no explanation, that's the magic button I use everytime I am stuck !